# Autofill Username and Password for multiple users in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, asyncstorage

[image]I'm creating a simple app in which I'm saving a session of a current user using a **token**. Once the user login and close the app next time user will go to the home page. But If the user logs out. Next time will go to the login page and now if the user enters the initial characters of the name. I want to **automatically get his/her name and password** and fill in the form like in browser and web apps
Any help?
If need more description. let me know in the comment section.

Comment: Can you show any sample design here? So that we can understand it more clearly

Comment: Please check now